# Can Present Perfect be used when I'm talking about "Actions that have been repeated many times up to now"

Tags: tense, present-perfect

I'm repeating Present Perfect and trying to dig into it a bit more. I've been reading a blog about this tense, which says that one of the reason to use Present Perfect is when I'm talking about actions that have been repeated many times up to now and it also provides this example:

> I’ve called you three times, where **have you been**?

Is it correct to use Present Perfect in this case? The reason why I doubt about it is that I can't find this case of using of Present Perfect in any other resource I've been looking through.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a link to the blog where you read this and found the example from. I recommend editing it in your question.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh it is in Russian

Comment: Then don't add. Because many won't understand after all (e.g. me).

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes you can.

It is one of the applications or you can say usage of **present perfect tense**. To specify events that have been repeated several times in the past and continues in the present too, as in the context of speech.

We also use the **present perfect** to talk about several different actions which have occurred in the past at different times. ***Present perfect suggests the process is not complete and more actions are possible.***

Several examples in this context are:

- The army **has attacked** the city five times.
- I **have had** four quizzes and five tests so far this semester.
- We **have had** many major problems while working on this project.
- They **have written** three letters already.
- We **have gone** to the beach many times.
- She **has been** down with fever for three days.

[Source of examples](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html)